# How to select a whole HTML block, including the tags in VIM?

Tags: vim, selection

Suppose I have:

```
<div id="help">
    <table>
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

How do I select the whole block, starting from `<div id="help">`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`vat`, as in Heptite's answer is the way to go.

Note that, depending on where the cursor is, you may need to type `at` a few more times until the whole `<div>` is selected.

Supposing the cursor is in a `<td>` you'd need `vatatatat` to select the whole `<div>`:

```
<div>      ^  at
  <table>  |  at
    <tr>   |  at
      <td> | vat
```

Another option would be to search backward for `di`(`v`) or `he`(`lp`) and select the whole tag with `vat`:

```
?di<CR>vat
```

Answer (score 7):

Place your cursor within the opening or the closing  tag and type "`vat`".

See:

```
:help text-objects
:help v_at
```